# nlpaug BackTranslationAug throws RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 3954) exited unexpectedly

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, nlp, machine-translation

```
nlpaug version: 1.1.11

Mac OS
```

I am trying to do data augmentation using `nlpaug` library https://github.com/makcedward/nlpaug

The back translation is giving me below error:

```
import nlpaug.augmenter.word as naw

text = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
back_translation_aug = naw.BackTranslationAug(from_model_name='facebook/wmt19-en-ru', to_model_name='facebook/wmt19-ru-en',batch_size=2,force_reload=True)
print(back_translation_aug.augment(text))
```

**The error is**

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nlpaug/base_augmenter.py", line 98, in augment
    result = action_fx(clean_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nlpaug/augmenter/word/back_translation.py", line 70, in substitute
    augmented_text = self.model.predict(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nlpaug/model/lang_models/machine_translation_transformers.py", line 39, in predict
    src_translated_texts = self.translate_one_step_batched(texts, self.src_tokenizer, self.src_model)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nlpaug/model/lang_models/machine_translation_transformers.py", line 58, in translate_one_step_batched
    for batch in tokenized_dataloader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1186, in _next_data
    idx, data = self._get_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1152, in _get_data
    success, data = self._try_get_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1003, in _try_get_data
    raise RuntimeError('DataLoader worker (pid(s) {}) exited unexpectedly'.format(pids_str)) from e
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 3954) exited unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BackTranslationAug.augment` function expects a list of strings as an input. Try this:

```
from nlpaug.augmenter.word import BackTranslationAug


text = ['The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog', 'hello world']

back_translation_aug = BackTranslationAug(
  from_model_name='facebook/wmt19-en-ru', 
  to_model_name='facebook/wmt19-ru-en',
  batch_size=2,
  force_reload=True)

print(back_translation_aug.augment(text))
```

[out]:

```
['Fast brown fox leaps over lazy dog', 'Hello world']
```

---

The versions installed are:

```
! pip install -U nlpaug transformers sacremoses
! pip freeze
```

[out]:

```
...
nlpaug==1.1.11
sacremoses==0.0.53
transformers==4.26.1
```

Comment: Same error: RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 69574) exited unexpectedly

Comment: Which pytorch , transformers, nlpaug version are you using?